# Windows 10 Start Menu pops up on hitting any three keys in quick succession

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The Start Menu pops open whenever I hit three keys on my keyboard in quick succession.

I looked at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/957152/windows-start-menu-pops-up-automatically-without-me-pressing-anything) but none of the solutions apply to me.

Any idea how I can solve this, or if not, then debug this further (trace the process that triggers the start menu)?

FWIW, it's happening on an Asus GL552W with Windows 10 Home v1703 (Build 15063.413).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a glitch in my keyboard. I use a Microsoft Skulpt and the <kbd>F5</kbd> key was jammed down.

I have no idea why that would cause this behaviour though, but it's definitely the cause (I was able to replicate it several times).